# What is the significance of the following CSS rule? li em { color: red; font-weight: bold; }

Tags: css

I'm not really good at computers but I must take learn programming, but anyways, I know what the rule does but I don't know what is significant about it. (I'm not native English speaker so not making things easier)

Answer (score 0):

It sets the color of the text within the `<em>` tag (that is within `<li>` tag ) to red and it's font-weight to bold.

```css
li em {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one <em>two</em> three</li>
</ul>
```

That is a rather significant rule, assuming that the list item wasn't already styled that way - in which case the selector is `not significant` because the `<em>` element will inherit these styles from the list item anyway.

```css
li { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<ul><li>one <em>two</em> three</li></ul>
```

Comment: ah i see. so if i write li { color: red; font-weight: bold; } everything within the <li> tag is affected and li em { color: red; font-weight: bold; } is just the <em> tag right?